# How can I collect data for visualization of quick sort?

Tags: list-manipulation, animation, visualization, sorting

I know how to implement quick sort in Mathematica. But I don't know how to get the temp data for visualization, because I used recursion. I want the effect similar to this:

[image]

```
qsort[{}] = {};
qsort[{x_, xs___}] := Join[qsort@Select[{xs}, # <= x &], {x}, qsort@Select[{xs}, # > x &]];
qsort@RandomSample@Range@30
```

Comment: You can get the temp data by [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and `Reap`

Comment: You can also use `Trace`. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167291/how-to-debug-when-writting-small-or-big-codes-using-mathematica-workbench-mma/6168036#6168036), where I was showing how to trace the execution of merge sort implementation (not quick sort, but also recursive).

Comment: [Couldn't resist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8) :-D

Comment: @Szabolcs Unbelivable!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
n = 100; (*number of points*)
s = RandomSample@Range@n; (*the initial set*)
(*some aux functions*)
head[{x_, xs___}] := Select[{xs}, # <= x &];
tail[{x_, xs___}] := Select[{xs}, # > x &];

(*qsort function modified for sowing the information needed*)
qsort[{}] = {};
qsort[l : {x_, ___}] := Module[{lh, lt}, (Sow@{l, lh = head@l, x, lt = tail@l};
                                          Join[qsort@lh, {x}, qsort@lt])];

(*Perform the sort and extract the transformation rules for each step*)
t0 = (Reap@qsort@s) [[2, 1]] /. {l_, h_, x_, t_} :> Thread[l -> Flatten@{h, x, t}];
(*Delete unproductive transformations for speeding up the animation*)
t0 = t0 //. HoldPattern[x_ -> x_] | {} -> Sequence[];
(*Apply the transformations and get the list of succesive states*)
seqs = FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, s, t0];

(*Calculate the elements' paths to highlight them at each step*)
hL = ArrayPad[Unitize@Differences@seqs Rest@seqs, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}] /. 0 -> Undefined;

(*Plot it*)
pstyle = PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize@Medium];
ListAnimate[ j = Show[ListPlot[#[[1]], ImageSize -> 500], 
                      ListPlot[#[[2]], pstyle]] & /@ Transpose[{seqs, hL}]]

Export["c://test.gif", j, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

[image]