# How can I animate the sorting algorithm used by Sort?

Tags: animation, sorting, charts

I try to make an animation of the sorting steps taken by `Sort` like this but something goes wrong:

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 20]
step = 1;
Animate[BarChart[Sort[list, (step++ < limit && #1 < #2) &]], {limit,
1, 100}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: [Output all steps of Sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152478/27951) is perhaps the closest to your question, in that it implements the visualization *as an animated bar chart*. Also relevant: [How can I collect data for visualization of quick sort?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18430/27951).

Comment: I disagree about this being marked a duplicate. None of the linked answers actually show how to visualise the sorting algorithm employed by `Sort`. The linked answers all implement their own sorting algorithms, which is not what is being asked here.

Comment: `Animate[BarChart[
  Block[{step = 1}, 
   Sort[list, (#1 < #2 \[Implies] step++ > limit) &]]], {limit, 1, 
  100}, AnimationRunning -> False]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
list = RandomInteger[100, 10];
Animate[
 Block[{step = 1},
  BarChart[Sort[list, (step++ >= limit || OrderedQ[{#1, #2}]) &]]
  ],
 {limit, 1, 100, 1},
 AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

> [image]

Very nice idea, I must say. I don't know if I would've come up with that on my own.